# Função de parar (clearInterval), dentro do objecto não funciona

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho este objeto, funciona bem mas queria acrecentar uma propriedade para fazer stop, isso não está a resultar:

JS:

```
var kissesAni = {
    init: function () {
        kissesAni.callAni();
    },
    callAni: function(){
        window.setInterval(function(){
            kissesAni.makeImgAni();
        }, 30);
    },
    stop: function() {
        window.clearInterval(kissesAni.callFontFlakes);
    },
    makeImgAni: function(){
        ...
    }
};
kissesAni.init();
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('heya');
        kissesAni.stop();
    }, 5000);
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Miky_Frazao/af3wz1rm/2/)

Ou seja, faz o `console.log('heya')` mas a animação não pára.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisas colocar o retorno do setInterval dentro de uma variável, e então utilizar o clearInterval.

Tente algo como:

```js
var kissesAni = {
  interval: null,
    init: function () {
        this.interval = kissesAni.callFlakes();
    },
    callFlakes: function(){
        return window.setInterval(function(){
            kissesAni.fontFlake();
        }, 30);
    },
    stop: function() {
        window.clearInterval(this.interval); // já tentei com this em vez de "kissesAni"
    },
    fontFlake: function(){
       
    }
};
```

Comment: Resultou, Obrigado